# fixed digits data type in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want user to input only 11 digits , if not, an error should be occured on sql, what type of variable should I use in my sql code.

My current code :

```
st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE  User(idUser numeric(11,0) not NULL,uName char(30), uSurname char (30), uAddress varChar(500), primary key(idUser) )");
```

Comment: Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL? ...?

Comment: You should let the database generate the primary key values for you.  By the way, is this oracle?

Comment: on MySQL server I use code, numeric value will not be generated by Mysql, user will input them

Comment: you shouldn't be using the DB to do your data validation for you. What's wrong with doing `if (strlen($data) !== 1) { die("Invalid length"); }`?

Comment: I want database to check it, instead of my java code, it is fixed number always, user may input 9 digits instead of 11

Comment: I don't know how you would check that on the DB side, nor why you would want to.  If you want the DB to handle it, then let the db generate it for you.  If you want to ensure that the user enters an 11 byte string, then let your front end handle it.  I assume you'd be kicking it back to the user interface anyhow, so why take the extra steps to the db and back?

Comment: the key is public identification number so it is fixed as 11 digits. DB cannot generate it.

Comment: You can simply use int or int(11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make this kind of check on db side in MySQL you can use a trigger

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_user
BEFORE INSERT ON user
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.idUser = IF(NEW.idUser BETWEEN 10000000000 
                                     AND 99999999999, NEW.idUser, NULL);
```

The trick is to violate `NOT NULL` when `NEW.idUser` not in a proper range. If you are on MySQL 5.5 or higher you can also use `SIGNAL`.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7667b/1)** demo. Try to uncomment the last insert statement and see it won't succeed.

Comment: @sadullah Did you try a trigger approach?

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is numeric, you can use a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE  User(idUser numeric(11,0) not NULL,uName char(30), uSurname char (30), 
uAddress varChar(500), primary key(idUser), 
CHECK(idUser > 9999999999 AND idUser <= 99999999999) )'
```

Though you'll want to check if the datatype `numeric` accepts numbers large enough.  If not you could to use varchar

Comment: In MySQL [the `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html). Therefore adding it is useless.

Comment: @sadullah: the fact that you accepted the answer seems to indicate you are planning to use this feature. But MySQL lies straight to your face by accepting the syntax: the check constraint is completely ignored and will **not** prevent values to be stored outside the range. You will have to revert to a trigger as shown in peterm's answer